# How to secure/hide x-api-key when calling third party API's from Nuxt3 project

Tags: cors, nuxt.js, middleware, nuxt3

I'm creating a new Nuxt3 project where I'm calling third-party APIs, which use x-api-key to get data.

How I can secure my x-api-key? like using middleware or something else in Nuxt3 JS

API is working fine on PostMan but when calling from the project it gives CORS error.

Comment: What CORS error? And how is your CORS error relevant to securing your API key?

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely a common practive not specific to Nuxt, but here's how you can go about it in Nuxt 3. If you want to avoid exposing your third-party API key to the frontend at all, you'll want to keep that API key out of the `public` portion of the [`runtimeConfig` in `nuxt.config.ts`](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/runtime-config) and access it from [Nitro server endpoints](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server) that your frontend can call.

```
// nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ...
  runtimeConfig: {
    thirdPartyApiKey: 'somekindofkeythatsprivate',
    ...
    public: { // values here are exposed to the frontend },
  },
});
```

```
// server/api/thirdparty.ts
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    // Grab the api key from runtime config
    const { thirdPartyApiKey } = useRuntimeConfig();
    // Make a call to the api with the key included as the 'X-API-KEY' header
    const response = await $fetch('https://thethird.party/api/some/endpoint/', {
      headers: { 'X-API-KEY': thirdPartyApiKey },
    });
    // return the result of passing the response to some composable that does
    // internal logic of some kind
    return useSomeKindOfInternalLogic(response);
});
```

```js
// pages/index.ts
<template>
  <div>{{ data }}</div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  const data = $fetch('/api/thirdparty');
</script>
```

**NOTE:** You may want to consider locking this `/api/thirdparty` endpoint down in some way, because even though you've hidden the api key from the frontend/consumers, this endpoint still can be called from anywhere, not just from your components on the frontend.